# Direct File System Function Calls on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, file, system, call

I was looking up things on different methods for coding to find rootkits, and I came upon a question here, actually, that mentioned one way to detect them was to scan for files using the windows API, and then using the direct file system, and see if there was any discrepancies (for some kinds of rootkits).

This made me question(s): How do you write code to directly access the file system?  What kind of function calls would be needed for this?  Is this something that can be done in C++ or would i need to go to assembly?

Any answers or guidance would be lovely!

Thank you,
-Stefan Z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty easy to read things directly...

(**Edit:** you can even do this without using Windows-specific header files -- see below.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *volume = fopen("\\\\.\\C:", "r");
    if (volume)
    {
        long long offset = 0;  // Sector-aligned offset
        setbuf(volume, NULL);  // Disable buffering

        if (_fseeki64(volume, offset, SEEK_SET) == 0)
        {
            char buf[1024];  // Multiple of sector size
            size_t cb = fread(buf, sizeof(*buf), _countof(buf), volume);

            // Process the data
        }
        fclose(volume);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The hard part is figuring out *what* to read, and how to interpret it.

A lot about NTFS is undocumented, but [some parts of it are documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470206%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Have fun researching.

Comment: So this set of function calls would go directly to the file system, and nothing would be hidden from it?

Comment: @StefanZuefeldt: Yes and no. If you have a rootkit, then it could certainly hide itself from this as well. It's just *harder* for it to do that in a consistent fashion, but completely possible. There is really no software-based mechanism that can hide a sufficiently powerful software-based rootkit -- it's just a game of whether the rootkit causes an inconsistency or not.

Comment: I was just wondering because there's got to be a way that the rootkit itself accesses its own code / data / files...  And what kind of inconsistency do you mean?

Comment: @StefanZuefeldt: The rootkit simply accesses its own data normally -- it's just that when *you* try to read its data, it can easily intercept the I/O request, detect that it didn't come from itself, and return zeros in the buffer wherever there would have been rootkit code. The only catch is that it would have to figure out *what* data to return to avoid causing a suspicion -- for example, if it says a file doesn't exist inside a folder, then it had better allow *you* to create a file with that name in the folder. If that fails, then you know something fishy is going on.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything, Mehrdad!  I do appreciate this all.. I like learning =)

Comment: @StefanZuefeldt: BTW, you might like reading [this](ftp://bonway.net/incoming/yubo/Inside%20Windows%20Rootkits.pdf).

Comment: Just as an aside I'm not sure the C API (e.g. fopen) is reliable here; the C runtime may do some pre-processing on the path.  In this particular case it will probably work, but it's probably safer to just directly call CreateFile().

Answer (score 1):

With the right permissions you can open the disk for read as a block device. You call createfile on the object manager path to the device (see the winobj tool from sysinternals), eg \.\Devices\HardDrive0.

From there you would have to read the file system manually by interpreting the bytes you read from the disk. That's not an easy task, since you have to have a custom implementation of fat32 or ntfs or whatever.

That's the only way I can think to do this. You might have luck using the fuse implementation of ntfs as the base to read the data.